# How to change date format in Magento's admin forms and grid?

Tags: magento, admin

How can I change the date format in Magento's admin forms and grid?

Currently in my system it is showing with format like **June 28, 2014** but in other system it is showing up like **2014/06/28**.

Does anyone know how to change it for admin panel?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get Date column in Admin Grid use this code

```
$this->addColumn('Date Column', array(

    'header'    => Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('Date Column'),
    'align'     => 'left',
    'width'     => '120px',
    'type'      => 'date', // specify this column is date type
    'format'    => 'y/M/d', // Format of the column 2014/06/03
    'index'     => 'date_column',
));
```

To get date picker in admin from

```
$this->addColumn('updated_at', array(

    'header'    => Mage::helper('yourmodule')->__('Updated At'),
    'align'     => 'left',
    'width'     => '120px',
    'type'      => 'date',
    'format'    => 'y/M/d',
    'index'     => 'updated_at',
));
```

you can change the format as like you want refer [**this**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Thanks Meenakshi, but this will work for only one form, where we will make above changes. But I wanted it for all over the admin panel.

Comment: How to achieve the same in Magento2 Grid.php block ?